# Sklearn logistic regression - adjust cutoff point

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a logistic regression model trying to predict one of two classes: A or B.

- My model's accuracy when predicting A is ~85%.
- Model's accuracy when predicting B is ~50%.
- Prediction of B is not important however prediction of A is very important.

**My goal is to maximize the accuracy when predicting A. Is there any way to adjust the default decision threshold when determining the class?**

```
classifier = LogisticRegression(penalty = 'l2',solver = 'saga', multi_class = 'ovr')
classifier.fit(np.float64(X_train), np.float64(y_train))
```

Thanks!
RB

Comment: Introducing special thresholds only affects in the proportion of false positives/false negatives, and thus in precision/recall tradeoff, but it is not the parameter of the LR model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, procedure of selecting threshold is done after training. You can find threshold that maximizes utility function of your choice, for example:

```
from sklearn import metrics
preds = classifier.predict_proba(test_data)
tpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(test_y,preds[:,1])
print (thresholds)

accuracy_ls = []
for thres in thresholds:
    y_pred = np.where(preds[:,1]>thres,1,0)
    # Apply desired utility function to y_preds, for example accuracy.
    accuracy_ls.append(metrics.accuracy_score(test_y, y_pred, normalize=True))
```

After that, choose threshold that maximizes chosen utility function. In your case choose threshold that maximizes `1` in `y_pred`.